# How to handle unsent messages in a concurrent queue in a web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, concurrent-queue

I am using a concurrent queue in my Web API as mentioned in thread
[How to maintain state or queue of requests in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452881/how-to-maintain-state-or-queue-of-requests-in-web-api)

But I am running into an issue where if the application pool is stopped or recycled it looses all the data in the memory.
Can someone help me as to how I can handle the same?

My use case requires accepting messages from different origins and putting in the queue and after every 5 seconds interval i am writing those messages to an input .txt file.

Comment: Store them somewhere external to the web app - like SQS or Rabbit.

Comment: But if every 5 seconds i send queued up messages to RabbitMQ and then again retrieve the same and write it to file, will it not impact the performance and will it not be a overhead?

Comment: Of course there will be overhead. Nothing is going to be faster than doing it all in memory. But in memory, by definition, is going to have a risk of data loss.